# show 2 digits max after floating point ... only if it is a float number with more than 2 float digits

Tags: php, math, floating-point

in my app i do some math and the result can be float or int

i want to show the final result with two digit after the decimal point max ... if result is a float number

there are two options  to do this

```
number_format($final ,2);
```

and

```
sprintf ("%.2f", $final );
```

but problem is ... if my final result is a int like `25` i end up with

```
25.00
```

or if final result is some thing like `12.3` it gives me

```
12.30
```

and i dont want that

is there any way to format a number to show 2 digits after float point ONLY IF it's a float number with more than 2 digits after decimal point  ? or should i do some checking before formatting my number  ?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

```
<?php
$number = 25;
print round($number, 2);

print "\n";

$number = 25.3;
print round($number, 2);

print "\n";

$number = 25.33;
print round($number, 2);
```

prints:

```
25
25.3
25.33
```

Comment: There is no difference between `12.30` and `12.3`, only between `"12.30"` and `"12.3"`, but you're working with a `float` as input, not a `string`, so there's no way to differentiate the two.

Comment: I agree, using round is more benificial... since you're using floats and not strings +1

Comment: @max Tim Pietzcker says absolutely right thing. You are working with float, not a string, so 12.30 is the same as 12.3

Answer (score 2):

I found another option. Cast to `float` to strip the trailing zeros:

```
echo (float)sprintf("%.2f", $final);
// or
echo (float)number_format($final ,2);
```

But these functions seems to round the number just like `round`:

```
echo sprintf("%.2f", 12.556); // 12.56
echo number_format(12.556, 2); // 12.56
```

So if you don't want this behaviour use this:

```
$final = 12.556;
echo (int)(($final*100))/100; // 12.55

echo (int)((12*100))/100; // 12
echo (int)((12.3*100))/100; // 12.3
echo (int)((12.34567*100))/100; // 12.34
```

Answer (score 1):

I think there is no such short bypass for it.
Manually check if it has 2 or more digits after decimal.

How to know if it has less one or zero digits after decimal ? Just multiply with 10 and check if it is an integer. If it is, print the number as it is. If it's now use '%.2f' to print it.

Answer (score 1):

You have to add an if condition, if it has more than 0 digits after the point. I don't see any other solution.

A simple and fast way to do this.

```
$final=3.40;
$decimalNbr= strlen(substr(strrchr($final, "."), 1));
$final = number_format($final,(is_float($final) ? (($decimalNbr>2) ? 2 : $decimalNbr) : 0));


echo $final;
```

Keep in mind too, that I added another decimal digits count before using the number_format.

Comment: 12.3 will output 12.30

Comment: You can create a function for multiple use.

Answer (score 1):

Try below function to maintain a constant 2 digits after decimal point

in case you want to change the number of digits change AFTER_DESIMAL_DIGITS value

```
function decimal_digit_maintainer($value){
    define("AFTER_DESIMAL_DIGITS ",2);
    $value_array = explode('.',$value);
    if(isset($value_array[1])){
        $value_array[1] =  str_pad($value_array[1],AFTER_DESIMAL_DIGITS,'0',STR_PAD_RIGHT);
    }
    return implode('.',$value_array);                                       
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you should do some checking. For example check if `ceil($number) > floor($number);` If you need specificly two digits, that is going to take more effort.

Answer (score 0):

I don't like this.

```
<?php
function format($number) {
    return preg_replace(
        '~\.[0-9]0+$~',
        null,
        sprintf('%.2f', $number)
    );
}

echo format(23), PHP_EOL;       //23
echo format(23.3), PHP_EOL;     //23
echo format(23.33), PHP_EOL;    //23.33
```

Comment: ..but `23.3` should output `23.3`

Comment: It should? In which case, all the input values match the expected output values, and nothing is required.

Comment: if decimal places are <= 2

Answer (score 0):

You can use this example

```
function num_format($number,$precision=0)
{
    $precision = ($precision == 0 ? 1 : $precision);    
    $pow = pow(10, $precision);
    $value = (int)((trim($number)*$pow))/$pow;

    return number_format($value,$precision);
}
echo num_format(71730116.048758);
//Output
//71,730,116.04
```